# Can't overload functions with union of function types

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to create a union of function types with different argument types, but in the union type the argument becomes 'never'. I could use union type as an argument and get the result I need, or use function overloading, but somewhy union of function types is not allowed. Here is the code example:

```
type FnA = (arg: 'a') => any;
type FnB = (arg: 'b') => any;
type Fn = FnA | FnB;
declare const fn: Fn;
fn('a'); // Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'
```

Is is a bug or does it work as intended?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is intended.
But, to make overloading, you should use intersection `&` instead of union `|`.

Here is working code:

```js
type FnA = (arg: 'a') => any;
type FnB = (arg: 'b') => any;
type Fn = FnA & FnB;
declare const fn: Fn;
fn('a'); //  ok
```